# gspread: 503 the service is currently unavailable

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have written a python code that downloads data from a google sheet and converts into a csv. I give a google drive id and it scans all the sheets in it, downloading them into local machine. I have ran this program many times, but today I got this error:

> raise APIError(response) gspread.exceptions.APIError: {   "error": {
>       "code": 503,
>       "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
>       "status": "UNAVAILABLE"   } }

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: It means that Google tries to prevent "unexpected" queries from going through. You can examine the error's detail by catching it. If this error is related to search functionality, you can check this [documentation](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2686272?hl=en) to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you share the code you use to download the data?

Comment: Here it is : https://github.com/pyerpude/Google-APIs-in-Python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having run into this error recently on a script on my own my research brought me to these two articles:
1. https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/503-service-unavailable
2. And this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188334/why-do-i-get-503-service-unavailable-errors-using-the-google-cloud-datastore-api)
Since you have run this code well in the past it looks to be an issue on google's side and you'll just have to run it again later.